# Java hibernate Query bit type postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a column in postgres db for delete records in bit type and set to not null:

```
delete bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT B'0'::"bit",
```

In my java spring model (AppUser):

```
@Column(name = "delete", length = 1, nullable = false, columnDefinition="BIT")
private boolean delete;
```

Problem is when I do query in my DAO:

```
String sql = "Select e from " + AppUser.class.getName() + " e WHERE e.delete = :0 ";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, AppUser.class);
```

java throws error below:

```
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting IDENT, found '0'
at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.parameter(HqlBaseParser.java:4640) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:915) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3554) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3406) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3278) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2935) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:615) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2702) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2658) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2527) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2443) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2408) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2121) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1899) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:498) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:754) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:319) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:198)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Just a side note: `delete` is a keyword in SQL, so it is not the best choice for a column name.

Comment: this is noted. thanks

Comment: Why not use a proper `boolean` instead?